# Зачем нужен continue? (Наглядный пример)

Tags: c#

У меня такая ситуация,что нужно объяснить концепцию операторов break/continue(зачем они нужны и как работают),с первым все понятно,а со вторым возникают проблемы с наглядным примеров использования на практике.

***Вопрос:*** Можете подсказать какой-нибудь наглядный пример где без него никак не обойтись?

PS в гугле все примеры высосаны из пальца либо не совсем понятно зачем "он" здесь нужен

PSS пример его работы в реальной программе(любой)

Comment: Так вам все-таки нужен *наглядный* пример или пример, где continue *необходим*?

Comment: наглядный+необходим

Comment: Немного не по теме, но например `continue` практически необходим при работе с `OpenMP`, `break` там нельзя использовать.

Comment: Пример, где без continue не обойтись, нельзя дать по определению, так как всегда можно обойтись вообще без циклов. Любую программу можно написать, пользуясь только операторами if и goto, остальные операторы нужны лишь для улучшения читаемости.

Comment: в этом то и проблема ученикам объяснить зачем он нужен :) @MSDN.WhiteKnight это для учебного примера

Answer (score 8, accepted):

При грамотном составлении условий, в операторе continue нет "необходимости". Сколько примеров не видел - везде можно было обойтись без него, поменяв немного условия. Но вот облегчить жизнь этот оператор может.

---

Первый пример, который приходит в голову - выйти из текущей итерации по условию:

```
for(...) {
    if(condition)
        continue;

    // code
}
```

Но данная ситуация не нуждается в `continue`, ведь проще в данном случае сделать отрицание условия и он даже не понадобится:

```
for(...) {
    if(!condition){
        // code
    }
}
```

---

Более "адекватный" пример использования, но менее очевидный - улучшение читаемости циклов с большим числом вложенности условий. Представим пример:

```
for(...) {
    // code 0
    if(condition1){
        // code 1
        if(condition2){
            // code 2
            if(condition3){
                // code 3
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Выглядит не очень "читаемо" даже без, собственно, самого кода внутри этих условий. Оператор `continue` позволяет эту пирамиду превратить в код вообще без вложенности:

```
for(...) {
    // code 0
    if(!condition1)
        continue;
    // code 1
    if(!condition2)
        continue;
    // code 2
    if(!condition3)
        continue;
    // code 3
}
```

Стоит отметить, что данный код выглядит несколько нестандартно что ли. Лично я видел такое буквально пару раз, уж не знаю, с чем это связано :)

Comment: Всегда можно написать такое условие цикла, при котором не понадобится проскакивать "неугодные" итерации. Другой вопрос, что условие может оказаться слишком громоздким и не очевидным для понимания, и вот в этом случае `continue` и `break` помогают разгрузить основное условие цикла и улучшить читаемость кода. Остальное, на мой взгляд, уже вкусовщина, как, например, куча `if - return` или один единственный `return` в методе (функции). Необходимости нет ни в одном из упомянутых случаев, можно делать как нравится или принято в команде. Но в целом +

Answer (score 3):

Этот оператор используется в циклах **for**, **foreach**, **while** и необходим для того, чтобы прервать выполнение текущей итерации цикла с места его вызова и перейти к следующей итерации. Естественно, как и **break** оператор **continue** оператор является оператором завершающим тело условия.

Пример:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    // Печатаем в консоль сообщение о начале цикла.
    Console.WriteLine("Iteration begin.");

    // Проверяем если i между 20 и 30, то прерываем дальнейшее выполнение цикла и переходим к следующей итерации.
    if (i > 19 && i < 31)
        continue;

    // Печатаем в консоль сообщение об окончании цикла.
    Console.WriteLine("Iteration begin.");
}
```

В результате для значений переменной **i** между 20 и 30 включительно в консоль будет выводиться только первое сообщение из цикла. Код цикла следующий после оператора **continue** будет пропускаться по выполнению условия, а указатель следующей строки для выполнения будет указывать на первую строку текущего цикла.

Comment: Но ведь проще сделать `if (!(i > 19 && i < 31))` и `continue` будет не нужен, что уже показывает, что тут нет **необходимости** в `continue`.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker Если у вас в цикле 100500 линий кода, то обрамлять их в условие в каждом таком месте моветон. Проще использовать **continue** оператор и код примет более читабельный характер и исключит кучу бесполезных вложений. Я дал тривиальный пример объясняющий логику этого оператора. Если у программиста фантазии нет чтобы понять как он это сможет использовать, то это уже проблемы программиста.

Comment: Во-первых нет ничего плохого в "обрамлении" кода по условию, особенно если это ровно 1 уровень вложенности. Во-вторых вот такие строки посреди "100500" линий кода, как у вас, и убивают читаемость кода в хлам. Табуляцию кода по условию видно глазами, а этот маленький `if` с `continue` еще нужно разглядеть.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker вы вправе чесать за ухом как вам заблагорассудится. И не столь важно чем вы это делаете - рукой или ногой. Лишь бы это было вам удобно. Суть почёсывания за ухом от этого не изменится.

Comment: Я все же больше предпочитаю программировать, а не чесать за ухом :)

Comment: Я тоже, но иногда проще переписать с вашей модель логику цикла на мою, чтобы избежать тройные и более вложения в **if**. Повторюсь, фантазия у всех разная и предпочтения в стиле написания тоже. Хотя учимся все мы одним и тем же правилам ООП.

Comment: Я вообще ни про какую логику не говорил, я сказал, что такие микрострочки с `continue` зло. Да и мой ответ к вашему никакого отношения именно поэтому и не имеет - я просто не видел, да и не вижу смысла рассказывать про continue, который можно избежать. На этом спор предлагаю и закончить.

Answer (score 2):

Оператор **continue** нужен для пропуска 1 итерации в цикле, чаще всего за каким либо условием.

Оператор **break** нужен для полного выхода из цикла. Также вызываться обычно за условием.

Обычно когда хотят показать "работоспособность" этих двух операторов приводят в пример самый обычный цикл **[for](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/for)**. Давайте для начала так и сделаем.

Вот первый пример с оператором **break**.

*Может быть (все может быть) ,что программисту встала задача вывести все числа от 0 до 10, но если условие вдруг срабатывает, срочно остановить выполнение цикла.*

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    if (i == 7)//То самое условие
        break;//Тот самый break
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

### Вывод таков:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Все как нам и нужно было. Как только условие выполнилось, процесс выполнения цикла прекратился.

Теперь с оператором **continue**.
*Теперь нашему программисту понадобилось выполнять цикл до конца и проводить какие-то операции со счётчиком. Но как только выполняется условие, приступить к следующей итерации, пропуская эту.*

Вот пример кода с выводом.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    if (i == 7)//То самое условие
        continue;//Тот самый continue
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

### Вывод:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
8
9
```

И я думаю, твой вопрос возник из-за частоты применения каждого из операторов. **break** используют чаще, и ситуаций для осмотра больше, а вот с **continue** возник вопрос.

Так вот отвечаю.

### Если изобразить цикл с обоими операторами, то вид будет таков для **continue**:

```
       условие
          |
=========   ========
```

А такой для **break**:

```
       условие
          |
=========
```

### Удачи в изучении **C#**.

**SeeSharp**